# How do I check whether a Ruby file/project actually uses a "require"-d dependency?

Tags: ruby

How, in Ruby, would I check whether a file and its required **files** use (makes use of in other words) a `require`-d dependency such as `octokit` for example? For example:

```
require 'octokit'
require 'somedir/somefile' # octokit NOT used here

def a
  puts 'a'
end

# Checked that octokit is not used, and gives us an error
```

Or:

```
require 'octokit'
require 'somedir/somefile2' # octokit used here multiple times

def b
  Octokit.user 'rafalchmiel'
end

# Checked that octokit IS used, and does not give us an error
```

Apart from actually checking (with a regex) whether a keyword is present in a Ruby source file (which would be both unreliable and slow), is there a way to detect that a Ruby file does in fact use the `Octokit` (or any other for that matter) module after it is `require`-d? I was wondering whether I would be able to implement a feature of the language Go which does a similar thing:

> The first step to making Go scale, dependency-wise, is that the
>   language defines that unused dependencies are a compile-time error
>   (not a warning, an error). If the source file imports a package it does not use, the program will not compile.

---

I've conducted a very tiny experiment. I created two executables; `a` and `b`:

`a` requires Octokit:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'octokit'
```

and `b` requires nothing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

This was the result when running each one:

```
➜  time ./a
./a  0.30s user 0.04s system 98% cpu 0.339 total
➜  time ./b
./b  0.04s user 0.01s system 95% cpu 0.045 total
```

Clearly an obvious difference. If many libraries are `require`-d and not used, this will slow down the execution of any Ruby app, be it large or small.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the `require` and seeing if it still works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby have very powerful `require`-ing and `load`-ing mechanism. `require` it is like `require`-ing feature and he doesn't reload files it's already loaded. Ruby keeps track of which files you've required and doesn't duplicate the effort.

> Strictly speaking, you do not `require` file; you `require` feature

P.S some example how know lib required or not:

```
 => require 'csv'
 #> true
 => require 'csv'
 #> false
 => if defined? CSV
 => puts "CSV defined"
 => end
 #> CSV defined
 => nil
 => ......
```

Part #2:

`If many libraries are require-d and not used` i think in Ruby is minimized. Look example lets say have built-in class `Time`:

```
=> t = Time.new
#> 2014-07-12 18:05:29 +0400
=> t.xmlschema
#> undefined method `xmlschema' for 2014-07-12 18:05:29 +0400:Time
```

Wow very strange because we have `xmlschema()` method in `Time` class. But:

```
=> require 'time'
#> true
=> t.xmlschema
=> "2014-07-12T18:05:29+04:00"
```

Resume:
Huge time loading `octokit` gem it is all about `octokit` developers.

Comment: I think this is a good answer. Ruby doesn't need this kind of functionality because it handles this sort of stuff behind the scenes. Still would be interesting to be able to know if a `require`-d library is actually used. Other than that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`require`ing a file in ruby runs its code (unless it has already been run). Besides loading the classes declared in it, this might have other side-effects which are not obvious from the direct use of the classes.

For example, rails intializers pattern, where rb files are located under the `initializers` folder, and run library configuration. These files do not contain any new method declaration:

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|

  ################  Global configuration  ################

  # Set the admin name here (optional second array element will appear in red). For example:
  config.main_app_name = ['MyApp']
  # or for a more dynamic name:
  # config.main_app_name = Proc.new { |controller| [Rails.application.engine_name.titleize, controller.params['action'].titleize] }

  # RailsAdmin may need a way to know who the current user is]
  config.current_user_method { current_user } # auto-generated
  # ...
end
```

In rails, these files are auto-required on startup, but in non-rails you would simulate this behavior by requiring them manually - should these be indicated as unused dependencies?

I don't think so.

Bottom line - even if there was some way to parse the file and look for uses of `require`d files (what about dynamic code? what about files `require`d *by* the `require`d file?) - it would be unable to unequivocally determine if the `require` is not needed for the code running...